# Locating Groovy installed via STS

Tags: filesystem, eclipse

I have installed the groovy plugin for eclipse as part of the Springsource Tool Suite Groovy and Grails support. This works well.

I now want to set my GROOVY_HOME environment variable so I can use Groovy from the command line using the Groovy already installed.  I have not been able to locate the installation of Groovy installed under STS.
How can I find the path for GROOVY_HOME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install it via apt-get, you may not need to set that.  I checked and groovy/groovyConsole seem to run properly.

If you do need to set it GROOVY_HOME should be /usr/share/groovy.

I've never used it, but I figured it out by looking at [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Installing+Groovy).  It tells you that GROOVY_HOME should have subdirectory of ./bin.

After the `apt-get install groovy && sudo updatedb && locate groovy | grep /usr | grep bin` it definitely looks right.

If you used a binary installer or put it somewhere else, those steps should help you find it.